# Green's result and Morita equivalence

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

This question is from this [note](https://www.impan.pl/swiat-matematyki/notatki-z-wyklado~/k_theory.pdf), 7.1.2, it says "by a result of Green", but I do not know how to get it.

> Let $A$ be a C$^*$-algebra, $\alpha\in \text{Aut}(A)$, define
>        $$M_{\alpha} = \{f\in C(M,\mathbb R):\ f(1)=\alpha(f(0))\}$$ (mapping torus).
>
> We have $\mathbb R$ acting on $M_{\alpha}$ by $(\beta_tf)(s)= f(s-t)$. Prove  that     $A\times_{\alpha}\mathbb Z$ is equivalent to 
>   $M_{\alpha}\times_{\beta}\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to take functions with values in $A$. [This](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/echters/Focused-Semester/lecturenotes/crossed-products-Echterhoff.pdf) document can help you, look at page 23. Basically, the $\mathbb{Z}$-action groupoid is obtained by relativizing the $\mathbb{R}$-action groupoid to a transversal, this procedure results in an equivalent groupoid (in the sense of Renault).